# Java Multiple Objects return same info

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a system to determine the type of a weapon and the damage of the weapon for a video game. I'm trying to instantiate two weapons with different stats, but when I use the method `getType();`, they return the same thing.

I tried using an ArrayList, but grabbing the type of the weapon from something such as `(arraylist name here).get(0).getType();` and `(arraylist name here).get(1).getType();` still return `"AK-47"`.

```java
ArrayList<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
        Weapon weapon = new Weapon("Desert Eagle", 5);
        Weapon weapon2 = new Weapon("AK-47", 3);

        weapons.add(weapon);
        weapons.add(weapon2);

        System.out.println(weapon.getType());
        System.out.println(weapon2.getType());
```

Methods:

```java
public class Weapon {
    static String type;
    static int damage;

    public Weapon(String type, int damage) {
        Weapon.type = type;
        Weapon.damage = damage;
    }

    public static String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

I want `weapon.getType();` to return `"Desert Eagle"` and `weapon2.getType();` to return `"AK-47"`.

I know it should be a simple answer, but I'm probably just over-complicating this for myself haha. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your variables are static, and you are updating them on the constructor, this means that every moment you are instanciating the class, you are overwritting the values, type is going to be always the last Weapon name. Try changing `static` for private, and `Weapon.` for `this.` and instead of `public static` on the getType method, use only public

Answer (score 0):

It is because your type is static
Change it to private String type;

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew I was over-complicating this lol

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` keywoard as it makes fields shared across every instance of that class

```
static String type;
static int damage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` from `type` and `damage` in `Weapon`. `static` means one value for the class globally, not one value per class instance (which is what you want). Also, `this.type = type;` and `this.damage = damage;` in the constructor.

```
public class Weapon {
    private String type;
    private int damage;

    public Weapon(String type, int damage) {
        this.type = type;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Also, you aren't currently using any values from your `List` (you kept the references you created, and are calling through those references). And prefer programming to the `List` interface over the `ArrayList` type (and you could use the diamond operator `<>`). Like,

```
List<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<>();
weapons.add(new Weapon("Desert Eagle", 5));
weapons.add(new Weapon("AK-47", 3));
for (Weapon w : weapons) {
    System.out.println(w.getType());
}
```

Outputs

```
Desert Eagle
AK-47
```